# How to get nested map from Cassandra Result Set

Tags: java, collections, cassandra, resultset

I have a Cassandra table like this:

```
create table Engine (
    primayval text,
    Dataval  map<text,<map<text, double>>,
    PRIMARY KEY (tradeddate)
);
```

How can I retrieve this in a Java nested map `Map<String,Map<String,Double>>` using `ResultSet-> getMap()` without JSON conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turned out to be quite straightforward :

```
    Map<String, Map<String,Double>> DataVal;
    Row rw = resultSet.one();
    DataVal=(rw.getMap("DataVal", TypeToken.of(String.class),new TypeToken<Map<String,Double>>() {}));
```

Comment: For completeness it is also possible to write DataVal=(rw.get("DataVal", TypeTokens.mapOf(TypeToken.of(String.class), TypeTokens.mapOf(String.class, Double.class)))). TypeTokens is an utility class from the Java driver, that usually makes less verbose code (but I admit, not in your case). Whichever way you choose, it is a good practice to cache your TypeToken instances (as constant fields) to avoid unnecessary allocation.